# SELECT query order by month

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015

Here is my query what i have tried:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,timeofpurchase) as 'Month', 
COUNT(*) 'Transactions', SUM(totalprice) as 'Total Sales'
FROM transactions 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,timeofpurchase) 
ORDER BY DATENAME(MONTH,timeofpurchase) DESC
```

[image: sql result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple workaround I can think of is to build another table that stores 1 and January, 2 and February, and so on. Then you do a join and order by the numerical column.

Answer (score 0):

Check for more information: [ORDER BY FIELD](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)

This should help:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,timeofpurchase) as 'Month', 
COUNT(*) 'Transactions', SUM(totalprice) as 'Total Sales'
FROM transactions 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,timeofpurchase) 
ORDER BY FIELD(MONTH,'January','February','March','April',...,'December') DESC;
```

Comment: Got this error: 'FIELD' is not a recognized built-in function name.